# Java SwingUtilities.invokeLater() timing with drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, swingutilities

Java Swing's `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` allows you to enqueue a thread to run after the last AWT event (user gesture) is processed.

Is `invokeLater()` guaranteed to wait until after the completion of a drag and drop gesture?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is important. An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your use case may help.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't enqueue a `Thread`, it adds a `Runnable` to the `EventQueue`.  The `EventQueue` then does an `instanceof` to determine the type of Object and if it is a `Runnable`, it calls `run`

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm debugging timing issues in someone else's code and unfortunately it's difficult to create a concise example; I'm moreso looking for expertise and guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `invokeLater` works is that it adds your `Runnable` to a list of objects that will be executed in sequence on the Event Dispatch Thread. The EDT is responsible for every event that is fired in your application, including mouse events, key events, repaints, etc. In order for `invokeLater` to wait until the end of a Drag and Drop gesture, the DnD gesture would have to block the EDT until it was fully complete. This would also mean that your application would become completely unresponsive until the DnD gesture was finished.

So, no, `invokeLater` will *not* wait until your DnD gesture has finished.

Comment: +1 for a key insight: `invokeLater()` can't predict what new `Runnable` will be posted as the gesture continues.

Answer (score 5):

No, [`EventQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) guarantees two things for queued instances of `Runnable`:

- The instances will be executed sequentially.
- That execution will be in the same order as the instances are enqueued.

Comment: [`invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) also guarantees that the queued `Runnable` will be executed after all currently pending AWT events have been processed.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Good point. I'm not sure about the benefit during DnD. I'd welcome a better answer.